# Set not null for a newly created column in PostgreSQL via Flyway SQL script

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, flyway

I have a Flyway migration script (in our Spring Boot application):

```sql
alter table bar
    add column foo_id int,
    add constraint fk_bar_foo_id foreign key (foo_id)
        references foo (id);

update bar
set foo_id = foo.id
from foo
where bar.foo_pid = foo.pid;

alter table bar
    alter column foo_id set not null;
```

It basically: adds a new column, makes it a FK to another table, fills it using existing data from the other table, and sets not null constraint.
Everything works as expected when I start the application backed with development DB.
However the application fails to start during tests with:

```
Migration V210111__foo_id.sql failed
----------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 23502
Error Code : 0
Message    : ERROR: column "foo_id" contains null values
Location   : db/migration/V210111__foo_id.sql
Line       : 11
Statement  : alter table bar
    alter column foo_id set not null
```

When I comment line #11 (and #12) the script succeeds, and when I look at the test DB (embedded postgres) I see that the record has indeed `foo_id = null`:

```
# foo table
id  pid
0   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

# bar table
id  foo_id  foo_pid
0   <null>  0000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

Notes:

1. The migration script works on some DBs but not others. Can't figure out which one is which!
2. There's no missing data. I can run the update part of the script myself while tests are paused and everything works just fine. It's just Flyway that can't run the migration.
3. Again, it's impossible that any `bar` row ends up with null `foo_id`, because, `foo.id` is the PK of `foo` table, `foo.pid` was the PK of `foo` table (and still is `not null`). Also `foo_pid` is `not null` and a FK to `foo` table.
4. There's a lot of migration before this one, adding new columns, removing existing ones, changing PKs, etc.

I'm not sure what could be the issue. Maybe it has something to do with the way Flyway runs migration scripts? The reason is when I run the migration against development DB there's only one migration script to execute (meaning the DB has everything already, including `foo.id` and `foo.pid`). But for tests, Flyway has to run all scripts (because it's a new empty DB). But as far as I can tell, Flyway runs each script in one transaction, so the data should be final when the next script gets executed.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be? Is there anyway to troubleshoot this more?

#### Update 1

> Again, it's impossible that any `bar` row ends up with null...

It's fair to trust PG over my words (even though I reviewed the schema multiple times). To eliminate any doubt about possibility of null values, I changed the update part of the script to:

```sql
--update bar
--set foo_id = foo.id
--from foo
--where bar.foo_pid = foo.pid;

update bar
set foo_id = 0;
```

And it still fails with the same error !

#### Update 2

There's one trigger which I don't think is relevant:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.update_modified_at()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin
    if row (NEW.*) is distinct from row (OLD.*) then
        NEW.modified_at = now();
        return NEW;
    else
        return OLD;
    end if;
end;
$function$
;
```

and each table has a `modified_at` column:

```sql
create trigger tgr_update_modified_at before
update on bar for each row execute function update_modified_at();
```

Comment: "*Again, it's impossible that any bar row ends up with null foo_id*" - Postgres proves you wrong with that assumption. I would guess you don't more rows in bar than you have in foo

Comment: Take it in steps one at a time and verify each step to see what part is not working.  Then you can post that specific part of your process and your code.

Comment: @Brad I'm not sure what steps I need take. If I disable the line #11 and check the data, I see the data is null. And when I try to run the same update query, it fills the data.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name please see my update.

Comment: Any triggers involved?

Comment: Added. Didn't think it's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

This part will probably not do anything:

```
update bar
set foo_id = foo.id
from foo
where bar.foo_pid = foo.pid;
```

since you just added the foo_pid column in table bar.
The clause

```
where bar.foo_pid = foo.pid;
```

is comparing null to foo.pid wich always fails and the statement will not update anything.

Comment: It's adding `foo_id` not `foo_pid`. `foo_pid` is there from the beginning. And as I said the script works for some data. Also see update #1.

Comment: Ahhhhhh.   I need new glasses.  I'll remove this answer.  If I could that is.....